# Why is the proj data so large?

Tags: math, anaconda, projection, gdal, proj

There is this project required by what appears to be the only free tool for working with gis and satellite rasters: Proj.

https://proj.org/

Which projects coordinate systems around and around.

For some reason it has an accompanying data source that is 550 mb.

Can anyone explain to me why it needs this? Aren't projections of various coordinate systems onto one another sort of what a gpu would do for example? Its all math so why does it need 550 mb of data?

Answer (score 1):

The proj-data file contains the parameters to perform coordinate conversions and transformations for different locations of the Earth.

Since those parameters can also come in the form of a grid (for grid-based transformation methods), and a grid can be a fairly large file, they add up to a whopping 500 MB data file (for versione 1.7). And as new grids are constantly made available, I expect that file to keep growing in the future.